# How can I find the norm and resultant of a pair of vectors passing through half a circle?

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry

I've been walking in circles (no pun intended) with this problem. It states as follows:

> A certain sugar is analyzed at an optical laboratory. The tecnician
>   passes two beams in the visible spectra one orange and the other
>   lightblue. These describe the vectors labeled **A** and **B** (see the figure
>   from below). Find the modulus of the resultant vector if it is known
>   the radius is 2 micrometers.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given on my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&2\,\mu m\\
2.&6\,\mu m\\
3.&2\sqrt 3\,\mu m\\
4.&4\, \mu m\\
5.&\sqrt 3\, \mu m\\
\end{array}$

Typically I would try to show some attempt to solve this problem but here I'm stuck at the very beginning. I tried all sorts of manipulations with the vectors. But I couldn't really reach to a logical arrangement to obtain a resultant. In other words I got tangled with too many arrows. Can somebody help me with this?.

If possible I'd appreciate a graphical and simple approach with less algebraic manipulations if possible. Please try to accompany the explanation with some sort of drawing so I can see what's happening because I feel this kind of question does really need that, otherwise I'll not be able to "understand" what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You are after $\left\lVert\vec A+\vec B\right\rVert$. You can get it using the fact that$$\left\lVert\vec A+\vec B\right\rVert^2=\left\lVert\vec A\right\rVert^2+\left\lVert\vec B\right\rVert^2-2\cos(\theta)\left\lVert\vec A\right\rVert\left\lVert\vec B\right\rVert,$$where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$. See the picture below:

[image]

Comment: I'm familiar with such equation but the problem lies on what would be the value for $\theta$? I get that is the angle between $A$ and $B$ but how do I find that angle?. An illustration or something would better aid me to get the idea.

Comment: Then $B$ would be $2\sqrt{2}$ but what about $A$. I don't know how to find the norm for that vector.

Comment: In this case, $\theta=120^\circ$.

Comment: And$$A=4\cos\left(15^\circ\right)=4\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}=2\frac{1+\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2+\sqrt6.$$

Comment: But wouldn't it be $\theta=60^{\circ}$?. Since when they are put together a triangle must be formed to obtain the sum?. Again, I believe a graphic or drawing should be added for visualization.

Comment: Oops! You are right: $\theta=60^\circ$.

Comment: I'm trying to get the ideas mentally but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I believe that you meant to form a right triangle with the flat side of the half circle with $A$ thus you reach to $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}$. Then by using cosines law that should be the answer. I know is a valid approach but again, it is not exactly the method which I was intending to look for, unless doesn't really exist another way.

Comment: It seems that Wolfram alpha doesn't obtain a simple expression seen here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%28sqrt%282%29%2Bsqrt%286%29%29%5E2%2B%282sqrt%282%29%29%5E2-2%28sqrt%282%29%2Bsqrt%286%29%29%282sqrt%282%29%29cos%2860+degrees%29%29

Comment: It doesn't appear in the alternatives given either.

Comment: I have added a picture to my answer.

Comment: That's nice. In fact while you were doing that I retried my mental calculations and obtained $2\sqrt{3}$ to be the answer. I thought that another way to obtain in a straight manner the "working angle" i mean the one to be used in cosines law would be by adding the angles of the bottom corners from the triangle at the base of the half circle, then you get the opposing angle outside the upper corner in the triangle formed by the cross between two vectors. With all this information I guess it can be solved. However as I mentioned my intended question was to scout for a trig free method.